# Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb binary for Node.js 18.14.0 (win32 x64)

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, node-oracledb

I'm using
nextjs: 13.1.6
oracledb: 5.5.0

I'm getting the following error:

```
Server Error
Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb binary for Node.js 18.14.0 (win32 x64) 
  Looked for 
    C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\.next\server\app\accounts\build\Release\oracledb-5.5.0-win32-x64.node, 
C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\.next\server\app\accounts\build\Release\oracledb.node, 
C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\.next\server\app\accounts\build\Debug\oracledb.node, 
C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\.next\server\app\accounts\editUsernamePassword\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-5.5.0-win32-x64.node, 
C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\.next\server\app\accounts\editUsernamePassword\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node

  Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
```

My code looks like this:
\src\app\accounts\editUsernamePassword\page.js

```
    \\first line of code
    import {oracleDB} from '@/library/database/oracle';
```

\src\library\database\oracle.js

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

//this is how to point to the Oracle Client without editing the PATH variable.
try {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: "C:\\pathToMyInstantClient\\oracle\\instantclient_21_9"});
} catch (err) {

  console.error('Unable to locate Oracle Instant Client.');
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
} 
/// ... then, go on to use the oracledb object
```

First question.  From the error message, it looks like it's not able to find the oracledb*.node file.  Is that correct?  At first, I assumed it wasn't finding the Oracle Instant Client, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Instead, the problem is that it can't find the oracledb*.node file.

Second, if my assumption (in 1) is true, why is it looking for the oracledb*.node relative to the app/accounts page?
I suppose I could copy the file there, but then I'd need to copy the client to every path that needs it.

Shouldn't it be looking for it here:?  I've confirmed the oracledb*.node files are here:

```
C:\path\to\my\project\MyProjectName\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release
```

What's further confusing to me is that this import doesn't always fail.
I have another file:
\src\library\oasis\abcHelper.js

```
    \\first line of code
    import {oracleDB} from '@/library/database/oracle';
    
    //then, it goes on to successfully use the oracle library
```

I have no idea why abcHelper.js is able to load the library, but page.js is looks for the library in the wrong place?

I did see this comment inside of oracledb.js, where it seems like they're discussing the issue, but I am not sure how to implement the solution:

```
  // For Webpack.  A Webpack copy plugin is still needed to copy 'node_modules/oracledb/build/' to the output directory
  // See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1156
```

When I do
npm run dev, I get this warning, but I'm not sure if that is the root cause.

```
wait  - compiling /accounts/editUsernamePassword/page (client and server)...
warn  - ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./src/library/database/oracle.js
./src/app/accounts/editUsernamePassword/page.js
```

My current next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that I haven't figured it out yet, but for anyone with this issue, the simplest workaround I've found is that the routes in the API folder work with oracledb just fine.  So on your page, just fetch an API route, then use the api to grab the oracle data, and send it back.  It's more back and forth, I guess, but since it's all happening on the server, I guess it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Update: for Webpack and node-oracledb 6.0, see [Bundling node-oracledb JavaScript apps with Webpack](https://medium.com/oracledevs/bundling-node-oracledb-javascript-apps-with-webpack-597c452f71f).

With Webpack and node-oracledb 5.5 you need a copy plugin in webpack.config.js to copy the node-oracledb binary:

```
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin([
            {
                // Copy the binary Oracle DB driver to dist.
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/oracledb/build/Release'),
                to: 'oracledb',
            },
        ]),
        . . .
    ],
```

Tips are in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1156#issuecomment-598017250

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Sorry, I'm new to to Nextjs and Webpack.  In my next.js project, I do see a next.config.js, but no webpack.config.js.  Am I supposed to create a new file in the same root directory?  I ammended my original post to include my current next.config.js (not sure if that's helpful)

Comment: Because this had the 'webpack' tag I assumed you were using it.  I'll let a Next.js expert continue further with you.

Comment: The reason why I added the webpack tag was because I also saw the issue 1156, which mentions a webpack solution, so I suspected that might be the cause.
 I do know that NextJS uses webpack, but  I haven't learned that portion yet.  Last night, I was able to figure out how to add the webpack config, but that didn't solve the problem.  In my original post, you can see that it looks for the oracledb*.node in a subdirectory of the page.  Even if I put it there, I'd need to put it in every single subdirectory of every page, which doesn't seem right.   Nevertheless, thank you for taking a look.

Comment: When node-oracledb 6.0 is released it will have a mode that doesn't need Oracle Instant Client.  This will make installation easier.

Comment: That would be awesome.  I'm new to next.js, and all this configuration has been daunting.   My understanding that this isn't an issue with the instant client.  next.js is able to run the node-oracledb Javascript code, but that code is looking for the oracledb.node file in the wrong place.  The file seems to be in the correct place, which is why my api routes are able to run Oracle fine.  However, my next.js "pages" are looking in the wrong folder as evidenced by the "Looked for.." errors I posted.  In the NEXT line, I tell it where to look 4 instantClient, but I'm not even getting that far.

Comment: Thanks again though, and have a great weekend.  My workaround (posted above) is working for me.  However, my "pages" are already running on the server side, I wish I didn't need to make a fetch call to my "api" route (which is also running on the same server), to do a database call.  I suppose it's an OK solution in the end, because as I understand it, next.js will automatically dedupe API fetch calls, so if two components need the same query, it'll automatically dedupe the calls for me.

Comment: node-oracledb needs Node.js and doesn't run in a browser if that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: Nextjs 13 has the new app folder.  By default, all components are React Server Components unless you indicate otherwise.  It should prerender on the server side.  You can have components render client side, but only if you indicate.  That's how I understand it, at least.  I. Still new to this.  Source: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals